# Saving score data in text file

Tags: javascript, html, storage

I'm making a simple dodger game and I recently implemented a scoring system. The way this works is that every 2 seconds, you will get a +1 score. At the same time, the game will also see if your current score passes your personal best score, which is stored in local storage. Everything is working, but I want to add a "world record" score which indicates the highest score any players that went on this website ever got. To do this, I planned to just store a number in the first line of a text file and then read the text file to compare it with my current score. In other languages like Python, I could totally do that. But I'm new to JavaScript and I can't seem to find a way to write in a text file (or any other sort of file). Is this simply not doable using JS?

Here is the code that runs every 2 seconds to keep track of score:

```
// Scoring system

setInterval(function() {
  if (dead == false) {
    document.getElementById("character").src = "images/playerJump.png"
    score += 1;

    if (score > highScore || highScore == null) {
      window.localStorage.setItem('high_score', score);
      if (score > recordScore) {
        recordScore.variable = score;
      }
    }

    highScore = parseInt(window.localStorage.getItem('high_score'));

    document.getElementById("scoreBoard").innerHTML = "Your score: " + score + " | Your personal best: " + highScore;
  }
}, 2000)
```

If there is any sort of solution to this, please let me know! I really don't know where to start with and any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Anything you want to store for multiple people needs to be stored on the server. Which means you need a backend language like PHP to store and read back the value. Most webhosts support PHP, and writing a value to a file and reading it back is trivial.

Comment: Oh okay, I see. Thanks for the information!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean or what you'r looking for but i will try to explain

Javascript is basically a front-end language you cant easily write/read files you must have a backend ( can be done with nodejs or php or even python)

NodeJS is a runtime environment for javascript that allows you to write backend code with javascript with some packages (native or not)

But if you want to write a really basic file. that's possible like this:

```js
var save = (function () {
    var a = document.createElement("a");
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.style = "display: none";
    return function (data, fileName) {
        var json = JSON.stringify(data),
            blob = new Blob([json], {type: "octet/stream"}),
            url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        a.href = url;
        a.download = fileName;
        a.click();
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    };
}());

var data = { data: "this is a file" };
var fileName = "example.json";

save(data, fileName);
```

In this way, it will download as a file. You cannot read/write directly.